# Jenkins pipeline calling multiconfig project and setting description

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline that calls a groovy script. Within that script I have a step that runs a jenkins multi-configuration job on 4 different agents.

I've using the jenkins description setter plugin to set a description for the job that is called. Works okay, but it sets the description for each of the configurations and not the parents. If I check the checkbox "Set description on multi-configuration build" this does kind of work, however, the multiconfig job just shows 4 lines with the same description:

"description"
"description"
"description"
"description"

Is there a way to avoid this repetition? I just want one description set. Can this be done within the groovey pipeline script itself as part of the build step?

````
test_job = build job: job_name,
            parameters: [string(name: 'DESCRIPTION', value: "Triggered by pipeline."),
                         string(name: 'ADDITIONAL_ARGUMENTS', value: "${ADDITIONAL_ARGUMENTS}"),
                         ],
            propagate: false```
````